# Excel: how to duplicate every row into the same column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, duplicate

Given a column like this in an Excel spreadsheet

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
...
```

How can I produce another column that looks like this (not manually copying and pasting of course since I have thousands of entries in the original column)

```
aaa
aaa
bbb
bbb
ccc
ccc
...
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, because your example does not specify how "yyy yyy zzz zzz" will be continued.

Comment: You can copy and paste "manually" very quickly with shortcuts: Ctrl+Shift+Arrow down, then Ctrl+C, then Ctrl+V.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=INDEX(A:A,ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/2,0))
```

and copy downward.

[image]

Notice you get *two* copies of each item.  If you use *3* in the formula, you would get *three* copies of each item.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the original order of the data:

- Write "1" into the *very first row* of a *new column* (for example cell B1) and "2" into the cell below it
- Select these two cells and click&drag the green square at the bottom right further downwards. This will fill the entire column with 1, 2, 3, ...
- Select all your data, including the new column
- Copy it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- Go to the first cell below your data
- Paste your data by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
- Select everything, including the new column, for example by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
- Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> until the new column has a cell highlighted in white
- Use Excel's sort button
- Delete the column that contains 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, ...

Before sorting, you'll have:

```
aaa  1
bbb  2
ccc  3
...  ...
aaa  1
bbb  2
ccc  3
...  ...
```

After sorting (before deleting the new column), you'll have:

```
aaa  1
aaa  1
bbb  2
bbb  2
ccc  3
ccc  3
...  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a solution where you can reference a dynamic array with one column or a single column from a table. This `LAMBDA` function has two parameters:
`col` is the array with one column with the values that should be repeated.
`n` is how many times to repeat the values:

```
=LAMBDA(col,n,INDEX(col,ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(ROWS(col)*n)/n,0)))(col,n)
```

I am not allowed to include screenshots yet, so I show you an example code where I used a literal as array and where each value gets repeated 2 times:

```
=LAMBDA(col,n,INDEX(col,ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(ROWS(col)*n)/n,0)))({"a";"b";"c";"d"},2)
```

The output should be:

```
a
a
b
b
c
c
d
d
```

Obviously you can reference a static array too.

Answer (score 0):

Power Query can also get the result:
Select the **Range**- go to **Data**- **From Sheet**- open **Power Query editor**- select the column and right click **Duplicate Column**- select 2 columns and go to **Transform**- select **Unpivot Columns**- Remove **Attribute** column- **Close and load to..**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If having your data sorted is OK:

- Select all your data
- Copy it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- Go to the cell below your data
- Paste your data by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
- Select everything (the original and the copied data), for example by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
- Use Excel's sort button

Before sorting, you'll have:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
...
aaa
bbb
ccc
...
```

After sorting, you'll have:

```
aaa
aaa
bbb
bbb
ccc
ccc
...
```